# flexigrid Ajax Filter by using flexOptions

Tags: flexigrid

I have a page data load in flexigrid, after loading there are several filters, onchange filter i try to reload the grid like this

`var data = {name: 'fltr_county', value: $("#fltr_county").val(), name: 'county_ene', value:$("#county_ene").val()}`

`$('.flexme').flexOptions({params: [ data ]}).flexReload();`

But got only 'page=1&rp=25&sortname=Borrower&sortorder=asc&query=&qtype=&county_ene=equal' posting array. Only last param value got.

How i can pass more filter in posting array?
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im new to Flexigrid.. but faced same situation and used this code.. its working for me.. im hopeful that your problem can be solved..

```
var query = $("#fltr_county").val();

var data = {"groupOp":"all","rules":[{"field":"fltr_county","op":"ew", "data": '"'+query+'"'}]};
$('#flex2').flexOptions({
    filters : data,
    qtype : "admin_client_contract_id",
    query : query,
    }).flexReload();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$('#useTimeRange').change(function() {
if( this.checked ) {    //limit events to timestamp range
    //alert("Checked " + startTime + " " + endTime);
    var data = {name: 'startTime', value: $("#startTime").val()};
    var data2= {name: 'endTime',  value:$("#endTime").val()};
    $('.flex5').flexOptions({params: [ data, data2 ]}).flexReload();        
}
```

Here's my UI and firebug:

[image: flexigrid extra params]

Answer (score 0):

according to me In data you are not passing parameters as per as syntax of json

try some thing like this

var data = {name: 'fltr_county', value: $("#fltr_county").val()},{ name: 'county_ene',value:$("#county_ene").val()}

I hope this will help